# UITabBarContrtoller achieve from a different class in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have the following problem:
There is a class that includes five tabs in the following way:

mainMenuClient.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MainMenuClient : UIViewController {
UITabBarController *tabBarController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITabBarController *tabBarController;

@end
```

mainMenuClient.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.view = contentView;
[contentView release];

ContactListTab *contactTab = [[ContactListTab alloc] init];
ChatTab *chat = [[ChatTab alloc]init];
DialerTab *dialer = [[DialerTab alloc]init];
MenuTab *menu = [[MenuTab alloc]init];
TesztingFile *teszting = [[TesztingFile alloc]init];
contactTab.title = @"Contact List";
chat.title = @"Chat";
dialer.title = @"Dialer";
menu.title = @"Menu";
teszting.title = @"TesztTab";

contactTab.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Contacts_icon.png"];
chat.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Chat_icon.png"];
dialer.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Dialer_icon.png"];
menu.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Menu_icon.png"];
teszting.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Contacts_icon.png"];
chat.tabBarItem.badgeValue = @"99";

tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
tabBarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);

[tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:contactTab, chat, dialer, menu, teszting, nil]];

[contactTab release];
[chat release];
[dialer release];
[menu release];
[teszting release];

[self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];

[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

In the contactTab class there are a UITableViewController.

contactTab.h

```
- (void)updateCellData;
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

There is a third class, which I would like to achieve is a method of UITableViewController's (from ContactTab).

So far I tried this:
When I tried to achieve the UItabbarController:

```
MainMenuClient *menu;
UITabBarController *tabBarControllerchange = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarControllerchange = menu.tabBarController;
[tabBarControllerchange setSelectedIndex:0];
```

When I tried to achieve the UITableViewController:

```
ContactListTab *contactListTab;
[contactListTab updateCellData];
```

Does anybody have an idea for this problem? Thanks. Balazs.

Comment: I don't get it? What is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the instance of your MainMenuClient:

define method in your MainMenuClient.h as:

```
+(MainMenuClient*)getMainMenuInstance;
```

Implement the following method in MainMenuClient.m as :

```
+(MainMenuClient*)getMainMenuInstance
{
     return self;
}
```

Now you can get same instance of UITabBarContrtoller in any class as :

```
MainMenuClient *menuClient = [MainMenuClient getMainMenuInstance];
UITabBarContrtoller *newTabBarController = menuClient.tabBarController;
```

You can do what ever you want to do with this new UITabBarController object.

Hope this helps.

Jim.

Comment: I try it, but I get the following error to the second row:

+[MainMenuClient tabBarController]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x12bd00

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '* +[MainMenuClient tabBarController]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x12bd00'